# Firebase content inside alert controller?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

It is possible to show content from a firebase database inside an allertcontroller? so the user can choose an option from the firebase list?

Comment: so you want to show a list inside an alert..?

Comment: yes it is possible indeed